# Mapping a function on selected elements of a data set

Tags: r, function, nested, tidyr, purrr

I have been trying to map the function bctau (and theil which is included in it) on selected elements of a data set. This function uses a two-step process to calculate an effect size for an AB single-case design. It requires two arguments (a = all the values in the baseline phase; b = all the values in the intervention phase). Below, you can find the two functions developed by [Tarlow (2017)](http://ktarlow.com/stats/r/bctau.txt).

```
library(Kendall)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)    
library(tidyr)

bctau <- function(a,b) {

# The bctau() function accepts two arguments, a and b, which
# are vectors for each phase in an AB single-case design


    n <- length(a) + length(b)

    ta <- 1:(length(a))
    tb <- (length(a) + 1):(length(a) + length(b))

    # if baseline trend is not statistically significant, 
    # return tau result (no trend correction)

        if (Kendall(a,ta)$sl > .05) {
            results <- Kendall(c(a,b), c(rep(0,length(a)), rep(1,length(b))))
            tau <- as.numeric(results$tau)
            p <- as.numeric(results$sl)
            se <- sqrt((2/n) * (1 - (tau^2)))
            return(list(tau = tau, p = p, se = se, corrected = FALSE))
        }

    # if baseline trend is statistically significant,
    # get Theil-Sen residuals

        theilsen <- theil(ta, a)
        slope <- theilsen$slope
        intercept <- theilsen$int

        correcteda <- as.numeric()
        correctedb <- as.numeric()

        for (i in 1:length(a)) {
            correcteda[i] <- a[i] - (slope*i + intercept)
        }
        for (i in 1:length(b)) {
            correctedb[i] <- b[i] - (slope*(i + length(a)) + intercept)
        }

        results <- Kendall(c(correcteda,correctedb),c(rep(0,length(a)),rep(1,length(b))))
        tau <- as.numeric(results$tau)
        p <- as.numeric(results$sl)
        se <- sqrt((2/n) * (1 - (tau^2)))
        return(list(tau = tau, p = p, se = se, corrected = TRUE, int = intercept, slope = slope, correcteda = correcteda, correctedb = correctedb))

}

theil <- function(x,y) {

# returns theil-sen slope and intercept estimates;
# x and y are two equal length vectors (x & y coords)

    n <- length(x)
    slopes <- as.numeric()
    ints <- as.numeric()
    for (i in 1:(n - 1)) {
        for (j in (i + 1):n) {
            slopes <- c(slopes, ((y[j] - y[i]) / (x[j] - x[i])))
        }
    }
    b <- median(slopes)
    for (i in 1:n) {
        ints <- c(ints, (y[i] - (b*x[i])))
    }
    results <- list(slope = b, int = median(ints))
    return(results)
}
```

My dataset consists of five columns:
1. Scalex: behavioral scales rated for the participants;
2. IDx: participants ID (note that two scales were completed for each participant);
3. Timex: Number of the session (it re-starts every time that the Phase changes);
4. Phase: Baseline (A) or Intervention Phase (B);
5. Ratex: Rating scale scores (from 1 to 20).

```
Scalex <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
IDx <- c("C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C2", "C2", "C2", "C2", "C2", "C2", "C2", "C2", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C2", "C2", "C2", "C2", "C2", "C2", "C2", "C2", "C2")
Timex <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
Phasex <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B")
Ratex <- c(4, 8, 10, 12, 15, 7, 7, 9, 14, 15, 16, 4, 3, 2, 2, 7, 7, 9, 14, 2, 3, 6, 6, 7, 5, 9, 11, 5, 6, 3, 4, 8, 7, 9, 3, 3)


db <- data.frame(Scalex, IDx, Timex, Phasex, Ratex)
```

What I would like to do is to group my data by scales and then apply the function bctau() to each participant. I tried to nest participants into scales and this was the result.

```
d <- db %>% 
  group_by(Scalex) %>% 
  nest()

# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  Scalex data             
#   <dbl> <list>           
#1      1 <tibble [19 x 4]>
#2      2 <tibble [17 x 4]>
```

Here's what one of the nested tibbles looks like. Phasex indicates whether the rating was conducted during the Baseline phase (A) or the Intervention phase (B), and Ratex indicates students' behavior rating scores.

```
d$data[[1]]
#[[1]]
#    # A tibble: 19 x 4
#   IDx   Timex Phasex Ratex
#   <fct> <dbl> <fct>  <dbl>
# 1 C1        1 A          4
# 2 C1        2 A          8
# 3 C1        3 A         10
# 4 C1        4 A         12
# 5 C1        5 A         15
# 6 C1        1 B          7
# 7 C1        2 B          7
# 8 C1        3 B          9
# 9 C1        4 B         14
#10 C1        5 B         15
#11 C1        6 B         16
#12 C2        1 A          4
#13 C2        2 A          3
#14 C2        3 A          2
#15 C2        4 A          2
#16 C2        1 B          7
#17 C2        2 B          7
#18 C2        3 B          9
#19 C2        4 B         14
```

I tried to write this code. I have used map2_df because I am using two variables. My code takes two columns at each time and uses the first as baseline and the second as intervention. Then it calculates the bctau values and other statistical parameters associated with it (standard error, p-values, etc.)

```
f <- db %>% 
  filter(Scalex == 1) %>%
  unite(ID2x, IDx, Phasex) %>%
  spread(ID2x, Ratex) %>% 
  dplyr::select(-Scalex, -Timex) %>% 
  data.frame()

#> f
#  C1_A C1_B C2_A C2_B
#1    4    7    4    7
#2    8    7    3    7
#3   10    9    2    9
#4   12   14    2   14
#5   15   15   NA   NA
#6   NA   16   NA   NA

f1 <- f %>% select(C2_A, C2_B)
> g <- map2_df(.x = f1[seq(1, ncol(f1), 2)], .y = f1[seq(2, ncol(f1), 2)], ~ bctau(.x, .y))
> g
# A tibble: 1 x 4
#    tau      p    se corrected
#  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>    
#1 0.784 0.0284 0.253 FALSE
```

The code seems to work only if the function bctau does not need to call the function theil (which means that the baseline trend does not require the correction across both A and B phases using the nonparametric Theil-Sen estimator). When the theil function is called, the package Kendall is also called and NA values seems to create some problems. However, I cannot get rid of them because the Baseline and the Intervention Phase doesn not have always the same length.

```
g <- map2_df(.x = f[seq(1, ncol(f), 2)], .y = f[seq(2, ncol(f), 2)], ~ bctau(.x, .y)) 

#WARNING: Error exit, tauk2. IFAULT =  10
#Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : Argument 7 must be length 1, not 6
```

I do not have necessarily to use purrr even though it would be nice.

**UPDATE**

I was able to get rid of part of the problem. If I remove the part of the code between ** within the bctau function (that I do not really need), the second error line does not show up anymore.

```
return(list(tau = tau, p = p, se = se, corrected = TRUE)) 
code removed from the bctau function: **int = intercept, slope = slope, correcteda = correcteda, correctedb = correctedb**
```

Unfortunately, `#WARNING: Error exit, tauk2. IFAULT =  10` is still there and it does not allow to report the corrected estimate in the outcome.

```
g <- map2_df(.x = f[seq(1, ncol(f), 2)], .y = f[seq(2, ncol(f), 2)], ~ bctau(.x, .y))

#WARNING: Error exit, tauk2. IFAULT =  10
g
# A tibble: 2 x 4
#    tau      p    se corrected
#  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>    
#1 1     1      0     TRUE     
#2 0.784 0.0284 0.253 FALSE
```

**UPDATE 2**

When I remove manually NA values from the column, the solution comes up. So my guess is that when the baseline correction is needed, the `theil` function is not able to calculate the new estimates if NA values are involved. Is there a way to tell the function not to consider NA values?

```
f2$C1_A
#[1]  4  8 10 12 15 NA

f2$C1_B
#[1]  7  7  9 14 15 16

#bl <- c(4, 8, 10, 12, 15, NA)
#i <- c(7, 7, 9, 14, 15, 16)
#bctau(bl, i)
#WARNING: Error exit, tauk2. IFAULT =  10

bl <- c(4, 8, 10, 12, 15) #remove NA manually
bl
#[1]  4  8 10 12 15
i
#[1]  7  7  9 14 15 16

bctau(bl, i) #calculate bctau
#$`tau`
#[1] -0.7385489
#$p
#[1] 0.008113123
#$se
#[1] 0.2874798
#$corrected
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to nest your data.frame by Scalex and by IDx and then use an anonymous function on your nested data.frame. I think that this code will give you what you need:

```
db %>% 
  spread(Phasex, Ratex) %>% 
  group_by(Scalex, IDx) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(m = map(data, function(d) bctau(a = d$A, b = d$B))) %>% 
  unnest(m)
```